# Comparing two tables that are the same and listing out the max date

Tags: sql, oracle, join, compare

I was wondering if it's possible to compare dates within the **same** table with same ID, but the catch is that there is an additional column that display the status. For instance, here's a table A:

[image: Original Table]

---

The results I would like to see is this:

[image: Results]

I know I could use a group by and max aggregate with ID to find the max date; however, I would like the status (Running/Stopped) column associated to be there. It would help me a lot.

Comment: To clarify, you want to get a `MAX(Date)` for each `ID`, with the value of `Status` corresponding to that value of `Date`. What about cases, when there are multiple entries for the same `ID` and `Date`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most databases, the fastest method (assuming the right indexes) is a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.date = (select max(t2.date) from t t2 where t2.id = t.id);
```

Even if not the fastest, this should work in any database.

Answer (score 0):

In case of Oracle, you can use the `KEEP` clause like this:

```
SELECT t.id,
       MAX(t.status) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY t."DATE") AS corresponding_status,
       MAX(t."DATE") AS last_date
  FROM tab t
 GROUP BY t.id
 ORDER BY 1
```

For this sample data:

```
+----+---------+------------+
| ID | STATUS  | DATE       |
+----+---------+------------+
|  1 | Running | 2018-02-03 |
|  1 | Stopped | 2018-04-04 |
|  2 | Running | 2018-03-24 |
|  2 | Stopped | 2018-01-02 |
|  3 | Running | 2018-06-12 |
|  3 | Stopped | 2018-06-12 |
+----+---------+------------+
```

This would return this result:

```
+----+----------------------+------------+
| ID | CORRESPONDING_STATUS | LAST_DATE  |
+----+----------------------+------------+
|  1 | Stopped              | 2018-04-04 |
|  2 | Running              | 2018-03-24 |
|  3 | Stopped              | 2018-06-12 |
+----+----------------------+------------+
```

As can be seen in this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9ecc14/8/1).

For the cases, when you have multiple entries on the same `ID` and `DATE` combination, it'll choose one `STATUS` value - in this case the last one (based on alphanumerical sorting), as I've used `MAX` on the `STATUS`.
The part `LAST ORDER BY t."DATE"` corresponds to how we choose `DATE` value in the group, i.e. by choosing the last `DATE` in the group.

See [this Oracle Docs entry](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/FIRST.html) on more details.